# What is a Dart Native Instance

Tags: dart, ffi

I'm building a Rust API for the [Dart Native Extensions API](https://dart.dev/server/c-interop-native-extensions).

I have found out about something called a "Native Instance".

I cannot find anything relating to it, or discussing it on google, or SO.

The functions in question (Rust link (C link)):

- [`Dart_AllocateWithNativeFields`](https://github.com/OptimisticPeach/dart-sys/blob/038e9265470540cec18e9b7d7744ca3fc97a029b/src/lib.rs#L3281) ([`C`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dda92904611699cd6410d189339f273245016e32/runtime/include/dart_api.h#L2442))
- [`Dart_GetNativeInstanceFieldCount`](https://github.com/OptimisticPeach/dart-sys/blob/038e9265470540cec18e9b7d7744ca3fc97a029b/src/lib.rs#L3444) ([`C`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dda92904611699cd6410d189339f273245016e32/runtime/include/dart_api.h#L2616))
- [`Dart_GetNativeInstanceField`](https://github.com/OptimisticPeach/dart-sys/blob/038e9265470540cec18e9b7d7744ca3fc97a029b/src/lib.rs#L3454) ([`C`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dda92904611699cd6410d189339f273245016e32/runtime/include/dart_api.h#L2624))
- [`Dart_SetNativeInstanceField`](https://github.com/OptimisticPeach/dart-sys/blob/038e9265470540cec18e9b7d7744ca3fc97a029b/src/lib.rs#L3465) ([`C`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/dda92904611699cd6410d189339f273245016e32/runtime/include/dart_api.h#L2633))

A few questions:

- What would `Dart_AllocateWithNativeFields` do? IE. What would one use it for?
- What would the use of a so called "Native Instance" be like for a Dart user?
- What is the `native_fields` parameter of `Dart_AllocateWithNativeFields` for/What should I supply it with?
- Should I even go about supporting this in an idiomatic Rust API?
- What is a "native field"?
- What is a "native instance"?

These functions have an unfortunate combination of little and bad documentation.

Comment: There isn't going to be much (or any) good documentation about Dart FFI because it's still in an extremely experimental stage.